# useEffect not triggered after useMutation using Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a parent component which has:

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DATA, {
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  });

  // Handle data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || error) return;
    setZendeskData(data);
  }, [loading, error, data]);
```

Then in a child component I have:

```
  const [createItem] = useMutation(CREATE_SESSION, {
    refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_DATA }]
  });
```

When the createItem is called and the refetchQuery runs, the useEffect in the parent component does not update the data.

What would be the best way to make sure data is always the latest?

Comment: Is the query passed to `refetchQueries` identical to what's passed to `useQuery`? One variable is named `GET_DATA` and the other is named `GET_SESSIONS`.

Comment: Sorry just a mistake when writting the question. but yes they are the same query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states):

> Let's return to our refetching example from the previous section. If
>   you click the refetch button, you'll see that the component doesn't
>   re-render until the new data arrives. What if we want to indicate to
>   the user that we're refetching the photo?

I think it pertains to your exact use case.  You would then add `networkStatus` from the `useQuery` as a `useEffect` dependency.